# Can I change the fillColor of a GeoJSON LineString with LeafLet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have a GeoJSON full of LineStrings (elevation contours), which I'd like to plot on a MapBox/LeafLet map.

When plotted, all LineStrings seem to form polygons (i.e. first and last coordinates in the array are equivalent).

Is it possible to change the fillColor of the LineStrings, given they look like polygons anyway?

EDIT

Below is the code I currently have:

```
var elevation950Style = {
color : "yellow",
fillColor : "yellow",
opacity : 0.4,
weight : 2,
};

$.getJSON('950.geo.json', function(file) {
   L.geoJson( file ,  { style: elevation950Style } ).addTo(map);
});
```

Comment: I believe, you can change it. Did you read documents ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly possible.

A good approach would probably be first to make sure your Line String is really a loop (as you say, if first and last coordinates are equal). Then simply convert it into a Polygon (create a new Polygon based on the same coordinates, remove the Line String), and it will be filled by Leaflet according to your `fillColor` option.

---

EDIT:

You could detect looped line strings after they are created by the `L.geoJson()` factory, create an equivalent GeoJSON feature with [polygon geometry](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#polygon), and replace the looped line string by the newly created polygon within your GeoJSON layer group:

```js
var myGeoJsonGroup = L.geoJson(myGeoJsonData), // build your GeoJSON layer group.
    geo, coords, first, last;

myGeoJsonGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  geo = layer.feature.geometry;
  coords = geo.coordinates;
  first = coords[0];
  last = coords[coords.length - 1];

  if (geo.type === "LineString" && first[0] === last[0] && first[1] === last[1]) {
    myGeoJsonGroup.removeLayer(layer);
    myGeoJsonGroup.addData({
      type: "Feature",
      properties: layer.feature.properties,
      geometry: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [
          coords // exterior linear ring
        ]
      }
    });
  }
});

myGeoJsonGroup.addTo(map);
```

Disclaimer: written as-is, not tested.

Note: in your case, you will certainly have elevation contours one within another. You may wish to build polygons with holes for the embedded contours. Otherwise, the fillings will stack, and you may not get your desired result if they are transparent.

Comment: thanks. I'll inspect each LineString to double-check. in the mean time, can you elaborate on "simply convert it into a Polygon (create a new Polygon based on the same coordinates, remove the Line String)"? Do you mean changing the way I load the GeoJSON onto the map? Or modify the actual GeoJSON?

Comment: I'll edit the above answer to be more specific on the conversion.

Comment: ghybs. sorry for being a noob, but I think the above code doesn't add anything to my "map" variable, right? also, what is "newPolygons" used for?

Comment: @Rodrigo thx for pointing the useless `newPolygons`. Of course you would add `myGeoJsonGroup` to the map at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If plotting line is the only criteria as SVG please check [geojson2svg](https://github.com/gagan-bansal/geojson2svg). You can just use CSS class in SVG path element or basic SVG's style. Check detailed [examples here](http://maps-on-blackboard.com/tag/geojson2svg/) for understanding of this small module.

Disclaimer: I am author of geojson2svg

Comment: Gagan, geojson2svg looks really good! I appreciate the effort you put in there. Because I'm nearly done with the project, I'll try finishing it with LeafLet, but keep geojson2svg in the back of mind for the future.